# How to monitor performance counters of HP Web Tour sample application apache server installed on local machine

Tags: performance-testing, performance-monitor

how to monitor Performance counters of HP Web Tour sample application apache server installed locally in system using jvisualvm or any other utility.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Monitoring Your Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/misc/perf-scaling.html#monitoring-your-server) and [9 Key Apache Web Server Performance Metrics to Monitor](http://blog.librato.com/posts/apache-monitoring) it appears that:

1. You need to keep an eye on Apache error log
2. You need to consider Apache specific metrics like requests per second, bytes per second, bytes per request. You should be also able to extract these metrics from your performance testing tool, normally they must report these kind of stats.
3. You need to consider infrastructure metrics like CPU, RAM, Disk, Network, Swap usage on the machine where you're running this sample application. The majority of operating system come with built-in monitoring tools i.e. [Windows Performance Monitor](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2014/07/17/windows-performance-monitor-overview/) or [number of command-line utilities for Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/) or a 3rd-party cross-platform monitoring solution like [PerfMon](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) or [Zabbix](https://www.zabbix.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your response can we use VisualVM to monitor Web Tour Apache Server?

Comment: You cannot monitor Apache server using VisualVM as it is not a Java-based application